# .htaccess file doesn't rewrite url and remains the same

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have searched through other posts but can't find a solution, I think its the url structure on the index
This is a list from database which contains a link to a details page(ad-details.php).

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <?php
    if($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ad_status = '1' AND  
    ad_type = 'Accomodation' LIMIT 10")){
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            echo "<ul class='list-group'>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                $amount = $row->ad_price;
                $famount = number_format($amount);
                echo "<li class='list-group-item'>"."<a class='active' href='ad-details.php?id=" .
                  $row->ad_id ."&title=".$row->url. "'>" .'<b>'.$row->  ad_title.'</b>'.
                  "</a>" ."<br>".$row->ad_town . ", " .$row->ad_state."." .
                  "<span class='badge'> ₦ $famount </span>" ."</li>";
              }
              echo "</ul>";
          }
          else{
              echo "<p style='color:red;''>No Data to be Displayed!</p>";
          }
    }else{
        echo "An error has occurred";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This is my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ad/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.php$ /ad-details.php?id=$1&title=$2    
    [L]
```

Comment: Can you post and example URL ?

Comment: Rewrite doesn't chnage url displayed on page it changes url after it reaches server, so if your url on page would be `"/ad/{$id}/{$title}.php"` then server through rewrite would see it as `/ad-details.php?id={$id}&title=$title`. You also dont need file extension - it could be added by rewrite.

Comment: Sample URL- http://localhost/Site/cmp/ad.php?id=17&title=this-is-a-title                                       I want to rewrite to the url to http://localhost/Site/cmp/ad/17/this-is-a-title           here is a new .htaccess                                                                                                                                                      RewriteEngine On                                                                                                       RewriteRule ^ad/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ad-details.php?id=$1&title=$2

Comment: Again. It doesn't work this way. Rewrite is for server so it know which script file to load, because your `/ad/17/this-is-a-title` would mean (to server) that you want to go to some directory. Mod will rewrite it to `ad-details.php?...` - now server knows waht to do with this url. On your website though you need to change links manually (some applications generate urls depending on rewrite possibility). Try to type this url in your browser: `localhost/Site/cmp/ad/17/this-is-a-title` and check if server goes to `ad-details.php` file. If it does then url was translated/rewritten for server.

Comment: You might want to add `RewriteBase /Site/cmp` after `RewriteEngine On`, because to server your link starts with `/Site/cmp/ad/...`. You might leave `^` sign instead, so url path wasn't rewritten from its beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule uses this regular expression to match URLs to rewrite:

```
^ad/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.php$
```

It will not match URLs that contain a '-', and will require a directory structure that includes a numeric-only directory.  This doesn't appear to be what you're trying to match against.  This will match URLs that resemble this format:

- ad/9/details.php
- ad/123/fleeber.php

You probably want something closer to this to match the `ad-details.php` page:

```
^ad-[a-zA-Z0-9]\.php$
```

If the list of pages that you're trying to match against includes dashes, you might include that in the regex pattern, as well:

```
^ad-[a-zA-Z0-9-]\.php$
```